# GNU parallel: how to format replacement string?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

I am trying to achieve the following and I want to do it on multiple processes **using GNU parallel.**

```
for i in $(seq 0 3); do
 var=$(printf "%.5d" $i)
 echo test_$var
done

 Output:
--------------------
test_00000
test_00001
test_00002
```

I tried this and it's not working:

```
parallel var=$(print "%.5d" {})\; echo test_$var ::: $(seq 0 3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're expanding the command substitution before you run parallel, which is why it fails.

You can avoid this with single quotes:

```
parallel 'var=$(printf "%.5d" {}); echo test_$var' ::: $(seq 0 3)
```

Comment: From version parallel-20140722 you can use perl expressions directly: parallel echo '{= $_=sprintf("%.5d",$_) =}' ::: {0..3}